# C#: pass an instance of a class from one module to another

Tags: c#, types, module, interface, dependencies

I have two modules, that could be present in the target either at the same time together, or on their own. Let's call them `ModuleA` and `ModuleB`.

`ModuleA` has a specific type, which I'd like to use in `ModuleB`, let's call it `SpecificType`. However, I'd like to still be able to include `ModuleB` on it's own (without the `ModuleA`).

Is it possible to resolve this issue by using interfaces / protocols? What I'm interested is that an object with a specific interface would be passed as a parameter, so it would be impossible to pass e.g. a string.

Example method in `ModuleB`:

```
// SpecificType is coming from ModuleA

public void MyMethod(SpecificType myVariableName) {

}
```

What I might want is something similar to this:

```
// SpecificType is coming from ModuleA, SpecificTypeInterface from ModuleB
// SpecificType implicitly conforms to SpecificTypeInterface

public void MyMethod(SpecificTypeInterface myVariableName) {

}
```

Comment: Is this question about passing type (try generics) or about assemblies (you can create C assembly to contain basic types and A, B uses it)?

Comment: You can't name variable `object` because it is a keyword.

Comment: The question is about using a type of one Module inside of another Module without depending on the first module. So I assume it could be resolved with use of interfaces

Comment: @RichardTopchii, sure - you need to use interfaces, and dependency injection. Then the specific module implementation could be injected during the execution, by means of some CI.

Comment: Does the caller (i.e. the application target) has to manually link ModuleB interface and ModuleA class?

Comment: You will need add third module that contains common types between ModuleA and ModuleB.

Comment: @Vernou thanks for clarifying. Please, post your message as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have some modules who need share interface/type, but you don't want dependence between this modules, you need a other module where is defined interface/type.

Generaly this other module has the prefix `Abstractions`, like [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions) or [xunit.abstractions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/xunit.abstractions/).

In you case :

ModuleAbstractions

```cs
public interface ISpecificTypeInterface
{
    void Foo();
}
```

ModuleA

```cs
public class SpecificType : ISpecificTypeInterface
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("From ModuleA")
    }
}
```

ModuleB

```cs
public void MyMethod(ISpecificTypeInterface spe)
{
    spe.Foo();
}
```

ModuleA and ModuleB have the dependence to ModuleAbstractions.